# How to tell if my wifi maintains a constant connection

Tags: wifi

I'm looking for how to tell whether or not my wifi is constantly connected. I've tried pinging google over a long period of time, and I didn't see any packet loss. Does this actually confirm it, or might there be some small periods where the wifi disconnects where internet traffic is buffered and resent to me once the connection to the gateway is reestablished?

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi WPA2 connection requires quite some time to be established (I guess up to a second), so if you ran a script which pinged your Wi-Fi router each 0.2 seconds (must be done under root since 1 second is the lowest for a normal user) you'll be able to tell whether reconnections occur. You can also follow the `journalctl -f` output which is easier and must be available for all users - all Wi-Fi reconnections must be logged in there (at least they are in Fedora 32 - can't say the same about other Linux distros).

As to:

> internet traffic is buffered and resent to me once the connection to the gateway is reestablished?

This is the normal mode of operation for TCP and such things occur even without Wi-Fi disconnects. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat